# List to a table represenation

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have a dataset formulated like this.

```
     set.seed(1221)
runs<-5
pd<-list()
for(k in 1:runs){
  p<-10
  n_b <- sample(1:6,p,replace = T) 
  bs<-c("S","M","L") 
  cl <- sample(1:3,p,replace= T) 
  Y<-4  
  d_km<-5.5
  cdata<-as.data.frame(matrix(0,p,20))
  for(i in 1:nrow(cdata)){
    cdata[i,1]<-n_b[i]
    for (j in 2:(n_b[i]+1)){
      cdata[i,j] <- rnorm(1,9,2)
    }
    cdata[i,8]<- sum(cdata[i,2:7])
    cdata[i,9]<-cl[i]
    if (cdata[i,9]==1){
      cdata[i,10]=max(0,cdata[i,8]-23)
    }
    else if (cdata[i,9]==2){
      cdata[i,10]=max(0,cdata[i,8]-28)
    }
    else{
      cdata[i,10]=max(0,cdata[i,8]-32)
    }
    cdata [i,11]= cdata[i,10]*Y*d_km
    if (cdata[i,9]==1){
      cdata[i,12]=max(0,cdata[i,1]-2)
    }
    else if (cdata[i,9]==2) {
      cdata[i,12]=max(0,cdata[i,1]-2)
    }
    else {
      cdata[i,12]=max(0,cdata[i,1]-3)
    }
    if (cdata[i,12]>=1){
      cdata[i,13]=sample(bs,1,replace = F)
    }
    else{
      0
    }
    if (cdata[i,12]>=2){
      cdata[i,14]=sample(bs,1,replace = F)
    }
    else{
      0
    }
    if (cdata[i,12]>=3){
      cdata[i,15]=sample(bs,1,replace = F)
    }
    else{
      0
    }
    if (cdata[i,12]>=4){
      cdata[i,16]=sample(bs,1,replace = F)
    }
    else{
      0
    }
    for(j in 13:16){
      if(cdata[i,j]=="S"){
        cdata[i,j+4]=runif(1,115,125)
      }else if(cdata[i,j]=="M"){
        cdata[i,j+4]=runif(1,135,145)
      }else if(cdata[i,j]=="L"){
        cdata[i,j+4]=runif(1,145,158)
      } else {
        cdata[i,j+4]=0
      }
    }
  }
  paxd<-cdata[,c(1,9,13:16)]
  pd[[k]]<-paxd
}
```

I need to represent the list **pd** as a data table where for each value of pd[[]] a matrix will be there. Something similar to this.
Day-1

```
 V1 V9 V13 V14 V15 V16
1   2  2   0   0   0   0
2   5  2   L   L   S   0
3   5  1   L   M   M   0
4   4  2   S   L   0   0
5   5  1   M   L   L   0
6   5  2   L   S   L   0
7   4  1   L   S   0   0
8   4  2   S   L   0   0
9   1  2   0   0   0   0
10  4  1   S   L   0   0
```

Day-2

```
 V1 V9 V13 V14 V15 V16
1   4  2   S   S   0   0
2   3  2   S   0   0   0
3   5  1   M   S   M   0
4   3  2   L   0   0   0
5   4  1   L   S   0   0
6   5  2   M   S   M   0
7   3  1   M   0   0   0
8   3  2   S   0   0   0
9   3  2   M   0   0   0
10  1  1   0   0   0   0
```

Basically I need to represent for each run a different matrix of **paxd**
Anyone can help ?

Can anyone help creating a matrix which will contain the data as per the k value ?

Answer (score 0):

I could figure this out on my own
I have created a new data frame to do that

```
pdf<-as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,pd))
```

This gave me the solution.